# How to modify file in a MSI package using .mst file (Transform)?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, packaging

I am totally new in packaging.

I want to modify a file in a MSI package using transform i.e. .mst file.

I am using Wise Package Studio 7.0 Version.

I tried replacing file using Files tab, but there is no option for replacing it. So I deleted the file e.g. `manager_db.vbs` & added a new file with same name.

Now when I am running installer with .mst file & it is giving me following error

```
"The specified File key ('manager_db.vbs') not found in the File table."
```

Can you anybody suggest me the proper way for modifying file in MSI package?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put all transformable files into dedicated cabs with the same Disk Id (Media Id). Using mst file you can change name of the cab for the Disk Id.